# For Loop for Django Ajax Form Submission

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I have a for loop which creates multiple modal popups and its corresponding form inside the modal pop up. I am submitting the form via Ajax method so as to not have the page refresh. However i am facing the problem that if i have multiple forms only the first form gets submitted correctly. The subsequent forms will submit the first form's value. Currently i have put my javascript in the for loop after the end form tag between `{% for form,post in zipped %}` and `{% endfor %}`. My thinking was that when the value `{{post.pk}}` changes I will listen in on a different form because I have used a unique form id `formy{{post.pk}}` as the selector in the javascript. However it is not working.

My script is:

```js
<script>                
    $('#formy{{post.pk}}').on("submit" , function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            
            data:{
                tag:$('#tag').val(),
                author:$('#author').val(),
                file_name:$("#file_name").val(),
                file_path:$("#file_path").val(),
                unique_id:$("#key").val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:$("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(),
            },
            success:function(){
                alert("UPDATED!!!!");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My html code is :

```html
{% for form, post in zipped %}
    <tr>
        <td><img src={{post.file_path}} style="width: 300px;"></td>
        <td>{{post.tag}} {{post.pk}}</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{post.pk}}"> Edit Tag </button>
    </td>
    
    <form  id="formy{{post.pk}}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{post.pk}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Tags</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        {{form|crispy}} {{post.pk}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Consider moving the ajax part inside of the for loop, so it can be unique for each form.

Comment: I did that but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I almost had the exact same question when researching how to solve this problem. I don't know 'JavaScript' very well (so there may be a much better way of achieving this) but, this worked for me. I hope it can work for anyone else stuck with this issue.

#1. putting the 'script' in the for loop
#2. referencing each data item by a specific id.

```html
<script>                
    $('#formy{{post.pk}}').on("submit" , function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            
            data:{
                tag:$('#tag{{post.pk}}').val(),
                author:$('#author{{post.pk}}').val(),
                file_name:$("#file_name{{post.pk}}").val(),
                file_path:$("#file_path{{post.pk}}").val(),
                unique_id:$("#key{{post.pk}}").val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:$("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(),
            },
            success:function(){
                alert("UPDATED!!!!");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am also not too familiar with 'Crispy Forms'. Just make sure each form element has a unique id. that matches the 'ajax' data.

example:

input id="**author{{post.pk}}**"

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:-**

```js
tag:$('#tag').val(),
author:$('#author').val(),
file_name:$("#file_name").val(),
file_path:$("#file_path").val(),
unique_id:$("#key").val(),
csrfmiddlewaretoken:$("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(),
            },
```

As above, you set post data. Which will pick 1st matched html elements. Not in current form.

**Answer :-**

Use js code as below.

```js
tag:$(this).find('#tag').val()


//Or

tag:$('#formy{{post.pk}}').find('#tag').val()
```

Use above syntax for all form fields.

---

**Improvements :-**

1. Actually, you don't need for loop on js code.
   You can use below syntax. Without forloop on javascript code.

```js
<script>                
    $('form').on("submit" , function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            
            data:{
                tag:$(this).find('#tag').val(),
                author:$(this).find('#author').val(),
                file_name:$(this).find("#file_name").val(),
                file_path:$(this).find("#file_path").val(),
                unique_id:$(this).find("#key").val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:$("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(),
            },
            success:function(){
                alert("UPDATED!!!!");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

2. you don't need `{% csrf_token %}` in every form. You only need it once in an page.